# how to make bootstrap form look smaller

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I create a form based on a bootstrap template and I want to make it look smaller.
I changed the zoom of my browser to 75% and then the size of the form is ok.
How can change the form to look smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `input-sm` to the classes on your inputs. See [Bootstrap Form Control Sizing Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)